# Google API where the uploader/author is from country

Tags: php, api, youtube

I would like to collect a list of videos using the Google API where the uploader/author is from  New Zealand and the video category is "News and Politics' or 'Non Profit and Activism'.

I have no problem using the category info to filter videos  (using PHP) I just don't know how to include the NZ filter for the uploader. The region filter gives me what's viewed not the author.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no "get list of authors in a location" call (atleast, not one published) I think the following will be the best you can do.: A bit bit of a walk though, and a far from perfect solution, but here's what I would see as best option:

1. Search for videos by location. As "location" isn't the location of the author, but the location they associate with the video, you you could be a New Zealander, uploading your holiday video from Japan and associate the video with Japan, and it won't show. Or you could be an Australian uploading a phot from their holiday in New Zealand, and it would show.
2. So to narrow it down a bit, after that, you can filter down by checking the location of the author, to exclude the Aussie, but you wouldn't get the Kiwi with the Japanese video. But that might give you a list of suitable authors.
3. To now catch videos you may have missed, from there, you can get a list of videos by those authors (one at a time - ouch) and merge together. This will hopefully then get a list of videos uploaded by Kiwis.

But, you also wouldn't get videos where the author hasn't provided a location; it's very hit and miss and invovles several calls a a bit of crunching.

Sorry it's probably not the answer you were looking for.

Comment: I had a feeling it would be something like that. It is for University research on documentary videos uploaded by NZders so I guess it will just take a bit of iterative filtering and matching. I had hoped someone would have a shortcut. Thanks Robbie for your answer.